# jooq-codegen-maven plugin for different db at the same time

Tags: java, maven, jooq

I use jOOQ and MySQL DB in my application. For integration tests I use H2 database and there is a problem. Is there some way to run jooq-codegen-maven plugin twice? I found some [maven example](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-plugins.html#Configuring_Build_Plugins) for this case. However, in two different cases, I must use two different dependencies. Can I somehow to include dependency in execution?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can have multiple `<execution>` elements in any Maven plugin configuration, e.g.

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
  <artifactId>jooq-codegen-maven</artifactId>
  <version>3.18.6</version>

  <configuration>
    <!-- Optional, shared configuration -->
  </configuration>

  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>first-generation</id>
      <phase>generate-sources</phase>
      <goals><goal>generate</goal></goals>
      <configuration>
        <!-- jOOQ configuration here -->
      </configuration>
    </execution>

    <execution>
      <id>second-generation</id>
      <phase>generate-sources</phase>
      <goals><goal>generate</goal></goals>
      <configuration>
        <!-- jOOQ configuration here -->
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Yes, i know it. I don't know how to configure the plugin: in first `<execution>` use `mysql <dependency>`, in second - `h2database <dependency>`. There is my problem

Comment: Thanks! And sorry, I already found the solution. I include my dependencies in `<plugin>...<dependencies><dependency>1</dependency> <dependency>2</dependency> </dependencies>...</plugin>`

Comment: Yes, precisely. Maven has its ways... :-)

Comment: could you post a skeleton of a complete example?

Comment: @JayZee: I've added some more Maven-specifics to the example. The jOOQ part is the same as always...

Comment: [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.jooq.pro:jooq-codegen-maven:3.13.1:generate (default-cli) on project XYZ: Incorrect configuration of jOOQ code generation tool. See error above for details. -> [Help 1]
I always get this error with this solution. If I only have one database and I don't use <executions> then it works, so my <configuration> element is correct. Any ideas?

Comment: @Volokh: Can you please ask a new question with all the details to reproduce your case? This answer is correct for the question asked here, but your question might be different.