# Jooq code gen with multiple xml schema files

Tags: java, jooq

I am using jooq codegen plugin in maven to generate code from xml schema file.

```xml
<configuration>
    <generator>
        <database>
            <name>org.jooq.util.xml.XMLDatabase</name>
            <properties>

                <!-- Use any of the SQLDialect values here -->
                <property>
                    <key>dialect</key>
                    <value>MYSQL</value>
                </property>

                <!-- Specify the location of your database file -->
                <property>
                    <key>xml-file</key>
                    <value>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/schema.xml</value>
                </property>
            </properties>
        </database>
        <generate>
            <daos>true</daos>
            <pojos>true</pojos>
            <records>true</records>
            <relations>true</relations>
            <globalObjectReferences>false</globalObjectReferences>
        </generate>
        <target>
            <!-- The destination package of your generated classes (within the 
                destination directory) -->
            <packageName>com.generated.classes</packageName>

            <!-- The destination directory of your generated classes. Using 
                Maven directory layout here -->
            <directory>${project.basedir}/src/generated/classes</directory>
        </target>
    </generator>
</configuration>
```

Is there a solution to generate code from two different schema files. Example: schema-other.xml.

Answer (score 1):

This is not yet supported by the `XMLDatabase` meta data source. The pending feature request is: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/6260

There are workarounds, though:

#### Using separate configurations

If the two schemas / files are not linked, you can run two independent code generation runs. If you're using Maven, you could do it like this ([see also this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26105204/521799)):

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
  <artifactId>jooq-codegen-maven</artifactId>
  <version>3.9.4</version>

  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>first-generation</id>
      <phase>generate-sources</phase>
      <goals><goal>generate</goal></goals>
      <configuration>
        <generator>
          <database>
            <name>org.jooq.util.xml.XMLDatabase</name>
            ...
            <properties>
              <property>
                <key>xml-file</key>
                <value>file1.xml</value>
              </property>
            </properties>
          </database>
          ...
          <target>
            <packageName>com.generated.classes.schema1</packageName>
            <directory>${project.basedir}/src/generated/classes</directory>
          </target>
        </generator>
      </configuration>
    </execution>

    <execution>
      <id>second-generation</id>
      <phase>generate-sources</phase>
      <goals><goal>generate</goal></goals>
      <configuration>
        <!-- jOOQ configuration here -->
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

If you're using standalone code generation, just configure two separate runs.

#### Merging the XML files

You could of course merge the two XML files manually into a single one, e.g. by using XSLT for automatic merging, or manually.

Comment: I tried this with two schema files,  but the second execution deletes the classes created by first execution if the package name for both of them is same. is there a property to override this ?

Comment: @Pradeep: No, there isn't. The output package belongs to a single generation run. What's your use-case for re-using the package between runs?

Comment: the idea is to have all the generated class files (from both schema files) under a single package.

Comment: Hmm. We'll support loading multiple files soon in the `XMLDatabase`. In the meantime, the simplest workaround I can see is to use XSLT to merge the two files into one, prior to running the code generator...